# No connected between view and controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm a newbie and I tried finding a solution of this error message:

> "The model item passed into the
>   dictionary is of type
>   'NerdDinner.Controllers.DinnerFormViewModel',
>   but this dictionary requires a model
>   item of type
>   'NerdDinner.Models.Dinner'"

There are similiar problem error but not the same context problem.
I believe that the problem is located in the edit.aspx and still i can't solve it.

DinnersController:

```
//
// GET: /Dinners/Create

public ActionResult Create()
{

    Dinner dinner = new Dinner()
    {
        EventDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7)
    };

    return View(new DinnerFormViewModel(dinner));
}
```

Models:

```
namespace NerdDinner.Models
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(Dinner_Validation))]
    public partial class Dinner
    {

    }

    public class Dinner_Validation
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Title is required")]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Title may not be longer than 50 characters")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Description is required")]
        [StringLength(265, ErrorMessage =
          "Description must be 256 characters or less")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Address is required")]
        public string Address { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Country is required")]
        public string Country { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Phone# is required")]
        public string ContactPhone { get; set; }
    }
}


namespace NerdDinner.Controllers
{
    public class DinnerFormViewModel
    {

        private static string[] _countries = new[] 
        {
            "USA",
            "Afghanistan",
            "Akrotiri",
            "Albania",
            //... omitted for brevity
            "Zimbabwe"
        };


        // Properties
        public Dinner Dinner { get; private set; }
        public SelectList Countries { get; private set; }

        // Constructor
        public DinnerFormViewModel(Dinner dinner)
        {
            Dinner = dinner;

            Countries = new SelectList(_countries, dinner.Country);
        }
    }
}
```

Edit.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<NerdDinner.Controllers.DinnerFormViewModel>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Title" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
   Edit: <%: Model.Dinner.Title %>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Main" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

   <h2>Edit Dinner</h2>
   <% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
       <%: Html.ValidationSummary("Please correct the errors and try again.") %>
       <fieldset>
          <legend>Fields</legend>
           <div class="editor-label">
               <%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.Dinner.Title) %>
           </div>
           <div class="editor-field">
               <%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Dinner.Title)%>
               <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Dinner.Title, "*")%>
           </div>
           <div class="editor-label">
               <%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.Dinner.EventDate) %>
           </div>
           <div class="editor-field">
               <%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Dinner.EventDate)%>
               <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Dinner.EventDate, "*")%>
           </div>
           <div class="editor-label">
               <%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.Dinner.Description) %>
           </div>
           <div class="editor-field">
               <%: Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Dinner.Description) %>
               <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Dinner.Description, "*") %>
           </div>
           <div class="editor-label">
               <%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.Dinner.Address) %>
           </div>
           <div class="editor-field">
               <%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Dinner.Address) %>
               <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Dinner.Address, "*") %>
           </div>
<%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.Dinner.Country) %>
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Dinner.Country, Model.Countries) %>
<%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Dinner.Country, "*") %>
           <div class="editor-label">
               <%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.Dinner.ContactPhone)%>
           </div>
           <div class="editor-field">
               <%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Dinner.ContactPhone)%>
               <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.Dinner.ContactPhone, "*") %>
           </div>
           <div class="editor-label">
               <%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.Dinner.Latitude)%>
           </div>
           <div class="editor-field">
               <%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Dinner.Latitude)%>
               <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.Dinner.Latitude, "*") %>
           </div>
           <div class="editor-label">
               <%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.Dinner.Longitude)%>
           </div>
           <div class="editor-field">
               <%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Dinner.Longitude)%>
               <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Dinner.Longitude, "*")%>
           </div>
           <p>
               <input type="submit" value="Save" />
           </p>
       </fieldset>

   <% } %>

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: .. Fix up your question.  Read the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq, and be a participant of SO not just a user!.  Accept answers and upvote!

Comment: Can you show us the Edit function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your 'Create' action is going to load "Create.aspx" not "Edit.aspx", I suspect that is still pointing to Dinner as the model.

Answer (score 2):

Add the correct name of the view to the ViewResult.

```
public ActionResult Create() 
{ 

    Dinner dinner = new Dinner() 
    { 
        EventDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7) 
    }; 

    return View("Edit", new DinnerFormViewModel(dinner)); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Lazarus: Good option!
@Matthew: you too!
@FullmetalBoy: I think you just new in ASP.NET MVC. You only need create the action in controller, after that Right click on this action and creating the View, so that you will never wrong mapping between View and Controller. In the asp.net mvc home page is also have this tutorial. Hope this tips useful to you, man! IMHO.